# How to set Vagrant using virtual Box?

Tags: php, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to vagrant, I am trying to setup a project using vagrant/virtual box, What I have done till now.

1- I have installed vagrant 1.0.1
2- i have installed virtual box on checking its version which shows -- 4.1.44_Ubuntu
3- Now I have added the virtual box in project directory using below command (Although I needed the LAMP stack for my project on ubuntu) and my system config is (ubuntu 12.04 insatlled using wubi installer on widows 7 )--

```
    1- vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box

    2- vagrant init

    3- vagrant up hashicorp/precise32


Then it starts downloading the file from specified url (for first time it seems ok, But for all time it repeats the same process).

    Am I missing some steps for congiuring it using vagrant ?

    Any help would be appreciated.
```

Here is vagrant file.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "hasicorp/precise32"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  # Boot with a GUI so you can see the screen. (Default is headless)
  # config.vm.boot_mode = :gui

  # Assign this VM to a host-only network IP, allowing you to access it
  # via the IP. Host-only networks can talk to the host machine as well as
  # any other machines on the same network, but cannot be accessed (through this
  # network interface) by any external networks.
  # config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.33.10"

  # Assign this VM to a bridged network, allowing you to connect directly to a
  # network using the host's network device. This makes the VM appear as another
  # physical device on your network.
  # config.vm.network :bridged

  # Forward a port from the guest to the host, which allows for outside
  # computers to access the VM, whereas host only networking does not.
  # config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # an identifier, the second is the path on the guest to mount the
  # folder, and the third is the path on the host to the actual folder.
  # config.vm.share_folder "v-data", "/vagrant_data", "../data"

  # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
  # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
  # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
  # the file hasicorp/precise32.pp in the manifests_path directory.
  #
  # An example Puppet manifest to provision the message of the day:
  #
  # # group { "puppet":
  # #   ensure => "present",
  # # }
  # #
  # # File { owner => 0, group => 0, mode => 0644 }
  # #
  # # file { '/etc/motd':
  # #   content => "Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine!
  # #               Managed by Puppet.\n"
  # # }
  #
  # config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  #   puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
  #   puppet.manifest_file  = "hasicorp/precise32.pp"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path (relative
  # to this Vagrantfile), and adding some recipes and/or roles.
  #
  # config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  #   chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
  #   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
  #   chef.add_role "web"
  #
  #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
  #   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
  # and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
  #
  # The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
  # ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
  #
  # If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
  # HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
  # validation key to validation.pem.
  #
  # config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
  #   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
  #   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
  # end
  #
  # If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
  # ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
  #
  # IF you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
  # chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
  #
  #   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
end
```

Comment: can you run `vagrant box list` after you added the box ? and before you run vagrant up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using one of the [Vagrant Cloud boxes](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utm_source=vagrantcloud.com&vagrantcloud=1), then you don't need to specify a box URL. And 'hashicorp' is misspelled in your Vagrantfile. It should be...

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
```

If you seem to be in a non-working state for some reason, just `vagrant destroy` your current box and `vagrant up` again. I also highly recommend [downloading](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) and installing the latest version of Vagrant (1.8.1 currently). Hope this helps.